# Has anyone come across a dialog splash screen

Tags: android

Mobile phone splash screen

I have a dialog style activity,When i display two dialogs in succession,The screen flashes.On some devices,it's just sometimes there.And on some devices,it's a must.
So,why this happened and how to avoid

Comment: I try to set windowEnterAnimation null,But it doesn't work